# convert json string into basic C# string array

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a very basic json string coming in from an API call.  The string looks like this:

```
{"zip_codes":["52149","52140","52160","54624","55931","54665"....
```

Now, all I want to is get the zip codes into a basic string array.  Here is what I have tried:

```
var zips = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string[]>(json);
//JObject jsonObj = JObject.Parse(json);
//string[] zips = jsonObj["zip_codes"].Children().ToArray();
```

None of those worked for me.  I know this a very basic thing to do, but I'm missing something.

Comment: Try the commented code again, but alter it to something like this `jsonObj["zip_codes"].ToObject<string[]>()`. (With `.Children().ToArray()` you will just get the individual json tokens as an array)

Comment: You are nearly there.. you need to defined a C# object with the same properties that are in your JSON object.  so make a class  with a string[] prop called "zip_codes",  then in 'JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string[]>(json);'     replace string[] with your new class type name.

Comment: I don't want a full blown object, just a simple string array so I can check if it contains a zip.  elgonzo's answer worked!  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

you can create a new class so:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace Example
{
public class SampleResponse1
{

    [JsonProperty("zip_codes")]
    public string[] ZipCodes { get; set; }
   }
}
```

and parse so:

```
string[] data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SampleResponse1>(json);
```